# Why a varible is empty after it is assigned by a right-value std::vector<int>?

Tags: c++, move

I use function:

```
std::vector<int>&& f() {
    std::vector<int> s;
    for (auto i : names) {
        s.push_back(this->f2(i));
    }
    return std::move(s);
}
```

the main function is:

```
int main() {
    auto g = f();
}
```

I use debugger monitor and find that before executing `return std::move(s)`, `s` is not empty, but why `g` is empty then?

Comment: You're returning a dangling reference, so the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: why would it be different before the vector is returned? You have something in `s` and nothing in `g` and *then* return it

Comment: `std::vector<int>&& f()` -- Why did you choose to return an r-value reference?  It isn't something that turns up in most user-written C++ code, so you must have had a reason to do this.

Comment: Dangling reference aside, it also matters when, where and how you check the contents. You must always step *over* the initialization or assignment, or it won't have happened yet.

Comment: Also, from the code you've show, it's very hard to figure out what the `this` pointer refers to. And `names`.

Comment: If you remove the rvalue reference and `std::move` call, things get moved out automatically. Furthermore, you can get even better than a move in numerous cases.

Comment: Because this vector was temporarily created in the function. I want to move it to `g` without incurring any assignment overhead.

Comment: @Sprout: just as a simple rule of thumb, *never* use `std::move` on a value you're returning. The compiler can already recognize that a return value is a xvalue (a type of rvalue), but using `std::move` inhibits some other optimizations (RVO/NRVO), so it has no upside, and at least a potential downside.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact, that `f()` returns a **rvalue reference** to a local object `s` in `f()`. This is a **dangling reference**, as the object referenced will not be existent anymore after `f()` returns. In `main()` you then retrieve an rvalue reference to said object, which will result in undefined behaviour.

To fix this you should return a copy of the local variable `s` like this:

```
std::vector<int> f() {
    std::vector<int> s;
    for (auto i : names) {
        s.push_back(this->f2(i));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Can *you* tell me what the `this` pointer refers to? Can you compile this code?

Comment: this will use RVO optimization right?

Comment: This is NRVO, and the optimization is permitted but not mandatory.

Comment: Note that, as the OP's code *seems* to be a member function of a class, that class *may* have an `s` member and the error *could be* that they've re-declared it inside the function. That would present a different problem with a (potentially) different solution.

Comment: @AdrianMole   ... except that the usage of `s` within the function refers to the variable defined in the function, even if there is something named `s` in an enclosing scope (such as a member of the class).

Comment: @Peter Indeed. But I've seen numerous problems posted on SO where the error is caused by a redeclaration of a member variable as a function-local variable.